# My Bootstrap popover doesn't show html in the loaded Wordpress excerpt

Tags: html, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap, popover

I have a Bootstrap popover and Bootstrapx Clickover extension with this javascript:

```
{$("#mypopover").clickover({
placement:'bottom', 
html : true
})
});
```

Html is as follows:

```
<a href="#" id="mypopover" rel="popover" data-content="<?php echo  pippin_excerpt_by_id(632);?><a href='<?php echo get_permalink( 632); ?>'>READ MORE</a>">Click to open popover</a>
```

The problem is that the READ MORE link works fine, but some popovers have additional html in their respective wordpress excerpts and that breaks the popover. What am I doing wrong??

Comment: can you be a little more specific the code you provided is not enough data..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might have to encode the html in the data attribute:

`echo htmlspecialchars( pippin_excerpt_by_id( 632 ) )`

Also, I would modify the `pippin_excerpt_by_id` function to append the read more link.